# Questions about returning const references

Tags: c++

```
const Date& default_date()
{
    static const Date dd{1970, 1, 1};
    return dd;
}
```

I was reading Stroustrup's book and I just couldn't get the code above.
It's about giving default values in a constructor.

The questions I have are

1. The function returns a local variable by reference. Shouldn't it be lost when the function ends end the variable goes out of scope?
2. And even if it doesn't go out of scope, since static variables are initialized only once and the function returns by reference, if you were to supply a default value with this function twice, wouldn't they be sharing same address therefore making them non-distinct?

Comment: there's no "default value" in this code. The code `{1970, 1, 1}` are *initializers* for the object `dd`. It is only initialized once, and every call to this function will return a reference to the same object.

Comment: The idea here is that `static const Date dd{1970, 1, 1};` is only called once during the lifetime of your program, even if `default_date()` is called multiple times. This is an optimization, because the default date will never change. Assuming `static const Date dd{1970, 1, 1};` was a costly operation this could save relevant processing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that your second question answers the first. Yes, `static` local variables stick around for multiple calls of the function, which is why the reference remains valid.

As for the second, that's correct, the two references would be to the same object. Since they are `const`, as is the object they reference, this usually isn't a problem.

Comment: There would not be a problem if it were a non-const object and reference either

Comment: @M.M It could be surprising in some circumstances, given that the function is called `default_data` and you might not expect to be able to change the defaults, especially not as the result of the function. I didn't mean it could lead to UB or anything, just that this meant there were fewer potentially surprising situations.

Answer (score 4):

When you define static variables in a function, they are only constructed once: when the function is first called.  Because the variable has static duration, it resides in a different area of memory, not on the stack.  It will remain in memory until your program exits, at which time all locally-defined static variables are destroyed in reverse order to their creation.

If you want to read what the C++ standard says about it start here:

- [[stmt.dcl § 4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4)
- [[basic.stc.static]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.static)